# React + Websocket + Redux

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, websocket, react-redux

I have a server (express), which refreshes data every 50ms.

I added a websocket server on this express server, and for a list of data I just send them through this websocket to the react interface.

So I have intensive data refresh.

On this interface (app react) I have several pages, each page contains specific data from the express server, in addition to these pages I have popups/moduls which are also displayed by certain server data.

So I have an intensive re-render on the whole application (the websocket being located in the app.jsx file and distributing the data via props to the children).

So I decided to use the react redux library to manage the data and sort them by category. Each page will have its action, and I would also have actions for popups in order to really update the application only when necessary.

The problem is that in the case of the websocket now I don't really know how to make it in a separate file, but called by the app.jsx, and that it comes to execute what is necessary for the reducing...

I saw that we could place it in a context but with my library I don't think I can do it...

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import useWebSocket, { ReadyState } from 'react-use-websocket';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { updateBattery, updatePopup, updateAlarm, updateOpcua, updateReport } from './actions';

export default () => {

  // States & Refs
  const [status, setStatus] = useState();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // Create websocket client
  const {
    sendMessage,
    sendJsonMessage,
    lastMessage,
    lastJsonMessage,
    readyState,
    getWebSocket,
  } = useWebSocket(process.env.REACT_APP_WS_URL, {
    onOpen: () => setStatus("opened"),
    onClose: () => setStatus('close'),
    onError: () => setStatus('error'),
    onMessage: () => {
      if (lastMessage !== null) {
        console.log(lastMessage?.data)
        console.log(lastJsonMessage)
    },
    //Will attempt to reconnect on all close events, such as server shutting down
    shouldReconnect: (closeEvent) => {
      setStatus('reconnect');
      return true;
    },
    reconnectAttempts: 1000,
    reconnectInterval: 2000,
  });

  // 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (lastMessage !== null) {
      console.log(lastMessage?.data)
      console.log(lastJsonMessage)
      //setData( JSON.parse(lastMessage?.data) );

      const payload = JSON.parse(lastMessage?.data);

      switch ( Object.keys(payload)[0] ) {
        case 'alarms':
          dispatch(updateAlarm(payload['alarms']));
          break;
        case 'popup':
          dispatch(updatePopup(payload['popup']));
          break;
        case 'battery':
          dispatch(updateBattery(payload['battery']));
          break;
        case 'opcua':
          dispatch(updateOpcua(payload['opcua']));
          break;
        case 'report':
          dispatch(updateReport(payload['report']));
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  }, [lastMessage, lastJsonMessage]);


  // Return
  // return ({
  //   alarms: {
  //     live:         data?.alarms_live    || {},
  //     history:      data?.alarms_history || {},
  //   },
  //   popups: {
  //     websocket:    status || 0,
  //     operator:     data?.opcua_data?.cycle_NbPopUpOpe || 0,
  //     battery:      data?.popup_battery  || 0,
  //   }

  //   // opcua:          data?.opcua_data     || {},
  //   // report:         data?.report         || {},
  //   // battery:        data?.battery_status || {},
  // });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Update, It works

```js
import { useEffect, useRef, useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { updateBattery, updatePopup, updateAlarm, updateOpcua, updateReport } from './actions';

const WebsocketContext = createContext(false, null, () => {});


export const WebsocketProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);
  const [val, setVal] = useState(null);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const ws = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {;
    const socket = new WebSocket(process.env.REACT_APP_WS_URL);

    socket.onopen = () => setIsReady(true);
    socket.onclose = () => setIsReady(false);
    socket.onmessage = (event) => {
      const payload = JSON.parse(event?.data);

      switch ( Object.keys(payload)[0] ) {
        case 'alarms':
          dispatch(updateAlarm(payload['alarms']));
          break;
        case 'popup':
          dispatch(updatePopup(payload['popup']));
          break;
        case 'battery':
          dispatch(updateBattery(payload['battery']));
          break;
        case 'opcua':
          dispatch(updateOpcua(payload['opcua']));
          break;
        case 'report':
          dispatch(updateReport(payload['report']));
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    };

    ws.current = socket;

    return () => {
      socket.close();
    };
  }, []);

  const ret = [isReady, val, ws.current?.send.bind(ws.current)];

  return (
    <WebsocketContext.Provider value={ret}>
      {children}
    </WebsocketContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useWebsocket = () => {
  return useContext(WebsocketContext);
};
```